# Java Happens-Before and Thread Safety

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, happens-before

Suppose I have a class which wraps a HashMap as follows:

```
public final class MyClass{

     private final Map<String, String> map;

     //Called by Thread1
     public MyClass( int size ){
         this.map = new HashMap<String, String>( size );
     }

     //Only ever called by Thread2
     public final String put( String key, String val ){
        return map.put( key, value );
     }

     //Only ever called by Thread2
     public final String get( String key ){
        return map.get( key );
     }

     //Only ever called by Thread2
     public final void printMap(  ){
       //Format and print the contents of the map
     }

}
```

This class is initialized via "Thread1".
However, the put, get, printMap and other operations are **only ever** called by "Thread2".

Am I correct in understanding that this class is thread safe as:

1. Since the reference to the map is declared final, all other threads would see the initial state of the map (happens-before is established).
2. Since put/get/printMap/etc are only ever called by Thread2, there is no need for mutual-exclusion.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So what you are asking is correct assumption. You do not need to make it thread safe if you can guarantee that it is only used this way. You can't pass a half constructed object around in java, so the "Constructor might not be finished" is not possible.

So if you do

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
          final MyClass instance = new MyClass(10);
          new Thread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                    instance.put("one", "one");
                      ....
               }

           }).start();
     }

}).start();
```

You are fine :) This is what you described, created by Thread1 but only used by Thread2. There is no way for the thread to collide with itself.

Thread-Safe is a different definition where the composed entity may safely be interacted with by multiple threads. In the case you described, that scenario does not happen, since you essentially have a thread that constructs and another that manipulates.

Comment: Then you don't even need 2 threads, just put `final MyClass instance = new MyClass(10)` in the second thread.

Comment: @m0skit0 I am not the one asking the question. BTW this is how a lot of rendering pipelines work, it allows you to minimize the number of locks so you can focus on what you want and not the bottlenecks. If the creation of an instance of a class is expensive then I think having two threads would be good. Either way it's not how the code is being used that is being judged here, it is what the author is asking.

Comment: "You can't pass a half constructed object around in java" -- You can, though. If I do `public static Foo foo = new Foo()` (note that the field is not `volatile`) from Thread 1, then it's possible for Thread 2 to read the `foo` reference before Thread 1 finishes the constructor. This is due to reorderings, and the fact that a constructor has _no_ special memory fences.

Comment: But that's not what we are talking about. it's not static either.

Comment: I don't think I'm dense, and there's no reason to be rude. I didn't downvote you. I was just pointing out a factual inaccuracy in what you had written.

Comment: You're the one posting that code, which is inefficient as you're creating 2 threads when one is enough. It also doesn't matter if the constructor is expensive or not since the second thread cannot start before it has finished, so you get no benefit from having it in another thread.

Comment: The code is used an instrument to the interaction. A production worthy impl would probably have 2 threadpools, one pool being CPU bound and the other possibly being I/O Bound.

Comment: @yshavit I am sorry you are correct, there is no reason for me to be rude. I am just frustrated why this trivial question from what looks like someone doing a simple interaction is getting blown into a theoretical discussion of the jvm.

Comment: I can't speak to m0skit0's motivations, just mine. I posted my comment because the notion that you can't see an object before its constructor returns is very intuitive, and probably common -- and yet, wrong. The only reason your code works is that there is an explicit happens-before edge created by `Thread.start()` (the inner one being the interesting one). You _can_ see an object before its constructor completes. If nothing else, I wanted to put that word of caution to anyone who might see your answer and use it as evidence to support their (incorrect) intuition.

Comment: I mean we are talking about class instances, not static instances references. Technically there are still no half constructed objects as the static reference does not belong to the object, it belongs to the class and would be getting manipulated outside the memory of the object being created.

Comment: @yshavit  I agree that you can pass around partially constructed objects, but am not sure if its because the constructor hasn't finished or the references to the fields have not yet been published (ie: the instance is non-null but it's field that was declared in the constructor is because it has yet to be published to other threads)

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about class instances. To clarify, if `public static Foo foo` starts as `null`, and Thread 1 does `foo = new Foo()`, and Thread 2 reads `foo != null`, it's _still_ possible for Thread 2 to see the `Foo` instance before Thread 1 finished the constructor.

Comment: @JohnVint It believe it could be either. The JLS allows basically any kind of reordering provided it doesn't run afoul of the HB edges.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit tricky to answer, because the JLS doesn't contain the concept of a class being thread-safe — all it specifies is relationship between actions (e.g. a write to a field, a read from a field, etc).

That said, by most definitions, this class is not thread-safe -- it contains data races caused by unsynchronized access to a not-thread-safe Map. However, your usage of it *is* thread-safe, because you safely publish `this.map` to Thread 2 after construction, and at that point `this.map` is only ever accessed by one thread, in which case thread safety isn't an issue.

In other words, this is only slightly more involved than asking whether `HashMap` is thread-safe when created and accessed only within one thread. The answer in that case is that `HashMap` is *not* thread safe, but it doesn't need to be.

Similarly, your class isn't thread safe, but it sounds like it may not need to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you stand to your definition of what will happen then **it would in fact be thread safe**.  That is, only thread-2 will put and get from the Map.

Since the Map is declared final, you do establish a happens-before relationship with respect to the write of thread-1 and read of thread-2.

> a) Since the reference to the map is declared final, all other threads
>   would see the initial state of the map (happens-before is
>   established).

Yes. An empty HashMap with `size` specified.

> b) Since put/get/printMap/etc are only ever called by Thread2, there
>   is no need for mutual-exclusion.

Yes as well, though this type of logic usually scares me in practice :)

Comment: -1 In worst-case scenario you can have an NPE as explained in my answer.

Comment: @m0skit0 Your strawman is blowing me away.  Not once in his question did he even mention whether or not the instance of `MyClass` will be null or does he care.  So why are you defending that answer?

Comment: Why don't you downvote yshavit too, as he has a similar answer to me and nothing like yours.  And while we're at it, frostjogla.

Comment: *"Not once in his question did he even mention whether or not the instance of MyClass will be null or does he care"* He didn't mention it because maybe he's not aware of this possibility. And I don't see anything wrong with pointing that out since it's a important issue.

Comment: why stop there? why not point out everything he may not be aware of?  or you can answer the question he asks

Comment: @m0skit0 The problem with the NPE argument is that _no_ object is thread-safe by that definition. If I publish a `String` by assigning it to a non-volatile static field, then I could get a NPE when I access that field. It won't come from any of the `String's` fields -- all the reference variables are `final` and thus will appear fully-constructed -- but the `String` reference itself could be `null`. Ditto for `ConcurrentHashMap`, and any other class. Most people would say this data race belongs to the class that declared the non-volatile static field, not to the referenced class.

Answer (score -1):

The question here is not about the class implementation itself, but about if the manipulation of the class you describe is thread-safe or not, so the class implementation doesn't really matter.

I can think of 2 possible ways of Thread2 accessing the `MyClass` instance.

1. Both Thread1 and Thread2 are run independently. In this case it's not thread-safe because Thread2 can call put/get/printMap/etc before the constructor running in Thread1 has finished, resulting in a NPE. The `MyClass` instance accessed by Thread2 can be null depending on how Thread2 accesses it. If it's a shared instance, when Thread2 accesses it, it can be null if `MyClass` constructor has not finished executing in Thread1.
2. Thread1 creates the instance and passes this instance to Thread2. In this case it is thread-safe, but this is actually irrelevant because there's no multi-thread access to this instance because Thread2 has to wait for the instance to be passed.

So in the situation you describe, the answer actually depends not on the class implementation but in how its instance is shared. And in worst-case scenario (way 1) it is not thread-safe.

Comment: -1 Unless the object's `this` is being escaped from the constructor, the constructor would finish before the object is accessible.  Since the hashmap is final, you will never get a NPE

Comment: Constructors don't half complete, what are you talking about?

Comment: @GregGiacovelli - the condition JohnVint is describing can happen if the reference to the instance is published in an unsafe manner.

Comment: @JohnVint Sorry I didn't explain myself correctly. I'm not talking about `map` being null, but `MyClass` instance being null.

Comment: @m0skit0 Well that is true, though we don't have enough information to come to that conclusion.  We assume, for the sake of this question, the `MyClass` instance is not null for thread-2

Comment: @JohnVint You can't assume that either, that's why I said *"Note that in your question you don't specify how Thread2 receives a MyClass instance, **which is important to determine the behavior of your program**."*. I always prefer to assume worst-case scenario.

Comment: @jtahlbom but that's not relevant to this question at all from the definition, he is asking if this class itself is threadsafe, not the code that is setting it up.

Comment: @GregGiacovelli Then you cannot answer the question because the answer actually depends on how the MyClass instance is shared, not on its implementation.

Comment: "Am I correct in understanding that this class is thread safe as:" you can't do anything from within this class to change how the constructor is invoked. This is childish to argue about

Comment: @m0skit0 That is not the question, the question is of the happens-before relationship of the `Map` instance with respect to thread 1 and thread 2

Comment: @GregGiacovelli The question here is not about the class itself, but about if that kind of manipulation is thread-safe. So obviously how to pass the instance matters.

Comment: Constructive comments on the downvoting are welcome, maybe I can learn something :)